# PHP calling python script and not returning result

Tags: python, php

I've got a simple PHP script that is using shell_exec to call a python script which should return the result "ok"

I can't seem to get this working - nothing is returned via the php file.  I can run a python script from the CLI and it works, and also run shell_exec to rn other functions and that works. So its something specific to python which I can't work out.

test.py:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

id = sys.argv[1:]
#Do some stuff wih id

#Return success
sys.exit("ok")
```

index.php

```
<?php

$command = escapeshellcmd('/root/bin/tracker/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

//This works
//$output = shell_exec("cat /etc/os-release");
//echo $output;
?>
```

Running /root/bin/tracker/test.py returns:

> ok

I've tried setting ownership of test.py to www:www-run and also checked +x permissions.

This is running on SLES 15.1
PHP 7.2.5
Apache 2.4.33

Comment: Try adding the path to the python executable as well. Something like: `/path/to/python /root/bin/tracker/test.py`.

Comment: Still not luck. Tried adding:

$output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/python3 /root/bin/tracker/test.py");

Comment: `sys.exit("ok")` indicates an error, according to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) `shell_exec` returns `null` when a error occurs. Use `sys.exit(0)` for success.

Comment: Thanks just for testing. Looks like some permissions issue as when I run php index.php it works, but not from the browser

Answer (score 3):

Found the issue.  Adding 2>&1 to the shell_exec clearly shows the error.

> $output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/python3 /root/bin/tracker/test.py 2>&1");

> [Errno 13] Permission denied

I moved the test.py file out of the root folder  and into /srv/www/htdocs and its working fine now.

Comment: Thanks you Greg for this answer, it saved lots of time.